# Can't access dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I accidentally changed the wordpress address on the dashboard from http:// to https:// and now cant access the dashboard to change it back. is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can log in to your **phpMyAdmin** and change the values "siteurl" and "home" in the database table `wp_options`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [what Castiblanco said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/44370/castiblanco), you should be able to solve this another way.

Download your wp-config.php and add those lines

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/' );
```

These values override the ones in the database. You should be able to log back in and change it back.

Comment: I tried this but i still can't log in. I'm only supposed to change the example.com to my site right?

Comment: @ann Sorry, had to go. Did you change anything to make it work? If you don't mind, you can mark either of the answers as accepted